# Is there a generic term for words "subscription" and "account"?

Tags: generic-term

Is there a general term designating both "account" and "subscription"? Is that "contract item"?

Context example: in AWS, you can have "accounts" and "master account". In Azure, you have an account with subscriptions.

Comment: Account is generic, in the same sense that a rung on a ladder is generic, or a feature on a map. Master account and sub-account are more specific. I think the Azure teminology is just Microsoft being Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Good that you provide a context. Anywhere with computer accounts there can be many levels of accounts depending on permissions and features available. These enforce levels of security. Each product names these as they will both to keep distinctions and sometimes to show that their product describes them better.

An *Account* meaning a log in identity is the most standard way to designate this. Further description adds permissions based on the need of the user to modify their own and others data. Admin and Master accounts describe administrators with increasing rights on up to the most empowered DBA.

Subscriptions would be a characteristic of what the account is used to access, which data feeds etc.

For a single word you might go with the most basic of *log in* or *log in ID*.